# Use multiple keys with LRUCache

Tags: python, python-3.x, lru

Can I use multiple/combination of keys in the `LRUCache` implementation from `Cachetools`? I want to use it like below

```
def fun(a,b): pass
x = LRUCache(maxsize=100,missing=fun)
```

and call it, I tried like below

```
x[a][b]
```

and

```
x[(a,b)]
```

but doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`missing` must be a function of a single argument, but you could use a lambda to wrap `fun` and unpack the tuple:

```
x = LRUCache(maxsize=100, missing=lambda args: fun(*args))
```

and call with:

```
x[(a, b)]
```

Comment: How do i go about calling this?